# Using select in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named message. I am trying to select the message from the table only when person_send_id and person_receive_id are distinct.
 I am able to select person_send_id and person_receive_id correctly. 
However, I don't know how to select the message. 
I was thinking of using a Select within a Select but I don't know how to implement it or if its the right way of doing it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_send_id, person_receive_id 
FROM `message` 
WHERE person_send_id = 21 OR person_receive_id = 21 
//AND SELECT message FROM `message` when these criteria are met
```

Message Table

```
message_id 
message 
person_send_id 
person_receive_id
```

Here is my table data.

[image]

I want to select only the first message where person_send_id and person_receive_id are repeating themselves.

So if I send 10 messages to the same person, I only want to grab only record with the message, in this case "Hello" for example

Comment: What if more than one message has been sent from sender to receiver?

Comment: That is fine. I only want to display one message per "conversation". In this case, it acts as a title

Comment: Can you give a snapshot of the table and what output you expect?

Comment: If you just want to get the `message`, you can just add it to your current select. e.g `SELECT DISTINCT person_send_id, person_receive_id, message`. That's what I understood from your question, or am I missing something?

Comment: If I add message, my query will return two rows. I only want to return 1 row with the first message

Comment: Did you try what @RobinCarloCatacutan suggested? It should solve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add the `message` to your current select.

```
SELECT DISTINCT person_send_id, person_receive_id, message 
FROM `message` 
WHERE person_send_id = 21 OR person_receive_id = 21;
```

And I assume you'll be wanting the latest one since it will be acting as a title.

Add `ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1`

e.g.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT person_send_id, person_receive_id, message 
 FROM `message` 
 WHERE person_send_id = 21 OR person_receive_id = 21 
 ORDER BY message_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: What a legend. Thanks a lot, I don't know why I didn't think of LIMIT

Comment: @Viteazul Cool! Glad it helped!